# Debugging headless install

Tags: raspbian, ssh, headless, debug

I just got a Model B which I intend to use headless only, via ssh (it's the only way I can use it for now either).

I followed [this steps](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_the_Linux_command_line) to "burn" Rasbian (downloaded from the official website) to a 8GB SD card.

`sha1sum` on the .zip matched the hash provided on the website.

I set up DHCP on my router and made sure it was working and listing the computers properly.

I inserted the SD card to the Raspberry, connected it to an Ethernet cable going through my router and then to the adequate power supply. A red led lighted up (the only one). I waited for 20 minutes and nothing popped up on the router's webpage showing the DHCP client list (which I refreshed, of course).

Files on the SD card and some info after my boot atempt:

```
debian@pc/media/boot: ls
bootcode.bin  fixup_cd.dat  issue.txt             LICENSE.oracle  start_x.elf
cmdline.txt   fixup.dat     kernel_emergency.img  start_cd.elf
config.txt    fixup_x.dat   kernel.img            start.elf
```

...

```
debian@pc/media/fc254b57-8fff-4f96-9609-ea202d871acf: ls
bin   dev  home  lost+found  mnt  proc  run   selinux  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   media       opt  root  sbin  srv      tmp  var
```

...

```
debian@pc~/Desktop/pi: df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  9.2G  6.4G  2.4G  73% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   396M  336K  396M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b9633229-5882-47e7-b0ef-9da23c0b5eca  9.2G  6.4G  2.4G  73% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   2.3G  3.0M  2.3G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7                                               442G  264G  157G  63% /home
/dev/sdd1                                                56M   19M   38M  34% /media/boot
/dev/sdd2                                               2.7G  2.0G  586M  78% /media/fc254b57-8fff-4f96-9609-ea202d871acf
```

dmesg (from /media/fc.../var/log/dmesg)

```
(Nothing has been logged yet.)
```

So... How should I proceed in order to debug this? Since dmesg is empty I assume there was some read error, hardware error, or something really simple I'm missing out...

Comment: Is the red LED the only one that ever lights up?

Comment: Green led should be flickering when it's reading from the SD card. I'd try re-burning it. Maybe on a different SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Pi is not running. You don't give enough information to tell what is wrong, but the following link gives diagnostic information.

http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

have you unmounted the sdcard probably after burning the image? I had a similar case before where the file system of the sdcard was corrupt after I pulled the sdcard out of the reader without unmounting it prior.

Maybe worth a try to reformat the sdcard.